# jscript onopen event failing to call function

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function when the browser opens (or reloads)

If I use:

```
window.onopen = window.alert("opened");
```

That works fine however:

```
window.onopen = winopen; 
window.onresize = winopen;

function winopen()
{
    alert("opened");
}
```

Does not. The `window.onresize` call *does* work, I'm also using the resize event to call a different function but put it in here just to test whether the function call worked at all as I have the resize event function call working elsewhere.

Comment: I don't think there is an `open` event on window. The first one "works" because you actually invoke alert assigning the result of its invokation. I guess you need 'load' event.

Comment: Cheers, noob misunderstanding on my part

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're misunderstanding a fundamental thing:

```
window.onopen = window.alert("opened");
```

Is assigning `window.onopen` the result of calling `window.alert("opened")`, which will call the function regardless.

The second way is the correct way of assigning functions, but there is no such event as `onopen`.

If you want to call a function on each page load, just call it in your .js file without anything else. The file will be parsed and executed every time the page loads.

So basically, you want:

```
window.onresize = winopen;

function winopen()
{
    alert("opened");
}
winopen(); //Call it now.
```

In some cases, you may want for the DOM to finish loading (all HTML was parsed, browser is ready for DOM manipulation), in that case, you can use `window.onload` instead of `window.onopen` in your example.

Comment: Just back at my PC and tried it, I'm a numpty! It works as you say, no need for a function call from an event - just putting the call in line causes it to call as soon as the window opens. Thanks.